# React useCallback hook is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have been trying to avoid re-rendering the child components (InputBox component) if the props are not changing but below code is not working as expected.
How can I fix it ?
How to avoid re-rendering InputBox component this as name is same but memoizedCallbacks is not memoized

```
<InputBox name={"test"} handleCb={memoizedCallback} id="name" />
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.12.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.12.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.8.3/babel.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel">

    // child
  var InputBoxSet = new Set();
const InputBox = React.memo(function InputBox({ name, handleCb }) {
  // should not re-render on name or handlerCB change
  console.log('%c InputBox renders', 'color: orange; font-weight: bold;');
  
  InputBoxSet.add(name);
  InputBoxSet.add(handleCb);
  console.log('%c InputBoxSet', 'color: orange; font-weight: bold;',InputBoxSet);

  return <input value={name} onChange={handleCb} id="name" />;
});

// parent
let mySet = new Set(); // to check if the callback function is new each it re-renders
const Greeting = React.memo(function Greeting(props) {
  console.log('%c greeting renders!', 'color: green; font-weight: bold;');
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log("handleChange");
    setName(event.target.value);
  };

  // despite memoizing callback , the memoize callback function is 
  // getting created new each time and hence causing the re-rendering of child
  const memoizedCallback = React.useCallback(
    (event) => {
      console.log('%c event', 'color: red; font-weight: bold;');
      handleChange(event); // doesn't call originial function unless event is changed
    },
    [event]
  );

  mySet.add(memoizedCallback);
  console.log('%c mySet', 'color: green; font-weight: bold;',mySet);

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name: </label>
        <input value={name} onChange={memoizedCallback} id="name" />
          {/* how to avoid re-rendering this */}
        <InputBox name={"test"} handleCb={memoizedCallback} id="name" />
      </form>
      {name ? <strong>Hello {name}</strong> : "Please type your name"}
    </div>
  );
}, areEqual);


function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return prevProps.name === nextProps.name;
}

function App(props) {
  console.log('%c render App', 'color: Yellow; font-weight: bold;');
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const nameArr = [];
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount((c) => c + 1)}>{count}</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <Greeting name={nameArr} />
    </>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `memo` is used when the state changes in the parent component but that child component doesn't depend on it. In your case, it seems that the passed `memoizedCallback` dependency changes every time the internal state in `Greeting` (when you type in the input field) changes, and thus the `props` to `InputBox` changes every time you type. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you but I know the reason for this .I event commented the reason for re-rending but how can i fix it.How can i avoid this

Comment: You cannot achieve this as long as you are passing the `memoizedCallback` that changes on every input change. Also, why do you want to avoid it? Re-rendering in you case is not that important/expensive.

Comment: I was just curious. I actually wanted to understand how useCallback works. I found out that it just avoids calling the actual function but it does create new wrapper function every time on rendering. If I have a child tree that takes this memoized callback as prop, it might be expensive to re-render this child every time, then how can i fix this re-rendering issue.

Comment: The only way to get `memo` and `useCallback` to not re-render/call the child component/function is to not update the props/dependency array passed to `memo/useCallback`. Once you understand this, implementing it is supposed to be straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

`InputBox` Component receives 2 props name (primitive type) and handleCb (reference type)
and the equality comparison used is

```
function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return prevProps === nextProps;
}
```

prevProps will be an Object, for ex -

```
prevProps  = {
  name: 'someName',
  handleCb: someFunc
}
```

nextProps will be an Object, for ex -

```
nextProps  = {
  name: 'someOtherName',
  handleCb: someFunc
}
```

Since both are different references, they will never be equal, as `{} === {}`
is always false.
Hence, `areEqual` will always return false and the component will re render.

What you need is -

```
function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return prevProps.name === nextProps.name;
}
```

Comment: I know I can fix by using       function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return prevProps.name === nextProps.name;
}  but I want to avoid rendering even when  i update only in Greeting

Comment: how to avoid re-rendering this <InputBox name={"test"} handleCb={memoizedCallback} id="name" /> as name is not changing but memoizedcallback is getting created each time